# How to set an image like another link in a website menu

Tags: html, css

I'm new to programming and I create a website but, I would add an image in my menu like another link of this menu. I’ve tried it but I can’t only move the image and I didn’t find something that can I help me on the web.

Here is my html and css code :

```css
header {
  background-color: dark;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu .bouton {
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

*/ #menu .bouton:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="home.html"><img src="logo.png" class="button" alt="Logo" title="Go home" width="30px" height="50px" /></a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="visit.html" class="bouton" title="Visit">Visit</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="contact.html" class="bouton" title="Contact">Contact</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="tourism.html" class="bouton">How make here ?</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="reservation.html" class="bouton">Reservations</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Kindly post what you've written so we can help you figure it out

Comment: insert your code, html and css, and i will help you

Comment: we need to look at your code. Adding image is as simple as adding text, you just have to find the right size of an image, or scale it properly.

Please insert here as an answer to these comments you html code of the menu.

Basically to use an image as a link, put the <img> tag inside the <a> tag

Comment: I’ve added the code, thanks you to your help

Comment: If `logo.png` and your *.html* file are in the same folder, the image must show.

Comment: Thank you Bazaim, but I will put my photo in my menu like another icon or link of the menu